# Cmake, link library, possible different endings of the name

Tags: cmake, linker, lib

I need to link the library. The name of the lib is LibName.VERSION.lib. VERSION can be different. How do I tell cmake that?

I use target_link_libraries. If I specify precisely the "LibName.VERSION" as a name it works, but the VERSION can differ. If I specify only the "LibName" it does not work. Is there any way without specifying the VERSION (without env var, cmake args, etc.)?

Comment: Find all files that match glob `LibName.*.lib`. Pick the first file. Link with it.

Comment: I thought about more neat solution. You know, like specifying somehow that the name can contain different endings. I have tried to use LibName.* in target_link_libraries and find_library, but I get "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class" while building the project. Thank you anyway though.

Comment: `I have tried to use LibName.* in target_link_libraries` target_link_libraries links with libraries. To find a file use `file(GLOB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using:

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    "${SOME_PATH}/lib/LibName.*.lib"
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).